# (Solved) Voice isn't always clear through AT-2035

Tags: microphone

I'm an audio noob and I would appreciate any help I can get here. I recently purchased an Audio Technica AT-2035 and I have it hooked up to a Focusrite Scarlett Solo Second Generation. I've been noticing that my voice often isn't coming through as clearly as I think it should be and is a little bit distorted throughout most of my recording. I made a quick clip to demonstrate it and also pointed out some of the worst parts of the recording. I didn't use any effects on this clip. Please take a look and I'd love to hear some advice, thank you!

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cth8Hf2fl2o)

Comment: Perrin - what platform are you using this microphone on? Also - what type of drivers are you using? If Windows.... are you using ASIO or other?

Comment: I"m going to assume the answer is Windows for now. If it is, please undertake the following: Google for and download the DPCLAT.EXE utility. Run this on your machine and then post a picture of the result.

Answer (score 1):

I too think it is probably your buffer settings. Usually it manifest as crackles and pops. It's definitely not anything to do with mic placement or gain or any of that. This is definitely a software/soundcard issue. First thing I would do is lower the buffer setting in your soundcard which will be accessible through your DAW preferences. Second I would make sure your using thd latest driver. I've had trouble with scarlett sound cards before.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed my bitrate and buffer size in OBS from 2500 to 6000 which seems to be making a difference. The biggest change I've made so far is changing my sample rate from 44.1 kHz in OBS to 48 kHz, which matches the sample rate of my ASIO driver. Here's the link to the new recording I made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SswL0Kylr-E

Answer (score 0):

Yes I hear what you are describing. Is it a condenser or just a regular dynamic mic? If it's a condenser it could possibly be a power thing. 
I would think that it's not your microphone as they are usually are not intermittent.

I used to have something similar when doing recordings and I ended up working out it was my phone that had a rechargeable battery. Every few minutes it would draw power to charge the battery and when it did this it made a similar sound to what you are hearing. I hear it, but it isn't something I have heard before.

Borrow another mic and do some more recordings and see if it still happens. I have a feeling that it could be another piece of equipment. Start turning off everything you can and bring things back on to see what triggers it.

Comment: The microphone I'm using is the AT-2035 which is a condenser microphone. This is the first microphone I've had so far which uses phantom power. I haven't noticed anything like this with the previous microphones I've had. I'm using a desktop so I don't think that phantom power is the problem but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like those little glitches are produced from buffer under-runs.

To be sure that this isn't causing the problem you might want to raise the ASIO buffer on the sound card.

Here is a [link](https://global.focusrite.com/optimising-a-pc-for-low-latency-audio) from Focusrite website on the topic of optimizing buffer values.

Mind that this will increase latency, if you're using the rig for live broadcast aplications.

Comment: I've made some changes in my recording software which has helped the audio quality so far. In OBS I changed the sample rate to match the sample rate of my ASIO driver. The ASIO driver is set at 48kHz but OBS was set to 44.1 kHz before. I've also increased my bitrate and buffer size so that both are at 6000. Here's a recording of what it sounds like now, do you have any more advice for me? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SswL0Kylr-E

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I gave Audacity a shot and instantly the problem was gone. I have no clue what was causing the problem in OBS but one test recording in Audacity showed me that all of the problems I found were 100% with OBS. All of the comments I received were very helpful though and did help me improve the quality of audio in OBS as well, thank you all!

Comment: If you think this is the correct answer just mark it as the answer.

Comment: Rather than making this comment an answer, you should make it an edit in your question.